# Android closing full screen view at the bottom is shunted off the screen

Tags: android, fullscreen, toolbar

I have a screen with a bottom toolbar aligned using the following styling

```
<style name="BottomToolbar" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/WHITE</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

When I first enter my screen the toolbar is nicely aligned to the bottom of the screen.

However, If I go to full screen mode (which hides the toolbar) and then return to normal mode (which re-displays the toolbar) the toolbar is now placed slightly off the screen. It looks as if its shifted down the amount of the status bar that is hidden in full screen mode.

[image]

If I background my app and then foreground it, the bottom toolbar is rendered correctly.

I have a bar at the top of the screen (instead of an appBar) and that is rendered in the correct place. I can not work out why it is misplacing the bottom toolbar.

Its as if when it is determining the bottom of the parent it is not adjusting for the fact its not full screen height anymore.

**What I have tried**

I have tried setting "fitsSystemWindows="true"" on my toolbar when exiting full screen mode but that doesn't make a difference.

I have tried setting the toolbar to INVISIBLE rather than GONE when hiding it but that makes no difference.

**EDIT 1 - Added Code snippet of how I go into and out of full screen**

I go into full screen using the following

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
      View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

I exit full screen by using the following code

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

**EDIT 2 - View is not shoved off the bottom, its height is too small**

It appears that the bottom view is not shoved off the bottom of the screen, its height is shrunk and smaller than it should be.

The bottom view is a LinearLayout with its height set to "wrap_content" but it appears the height is not calculated correctly as its shorter than its contents and hence the bottom of its contents are cut off.

**Edit 3 - devices the issues presents on**

Further investigation showed the issue only presents on devices which do not have the on screen navigation bar. For example the issue is on my Samsung 10" Tablet but not on my Nexus 5x.

Comment: Can you add some code (switch to full screen mode an go back from it)?

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code I use to enter/exit full screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remove the following flag the issue appears to be fixed

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
```

The Google doc for this flag is "*When using other layout flags, we would like a stable view of the content insets given to fitSystemWindows(Rect).*"
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

The docs say
"*You may also need to use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE to help your app maintain a stable layout*." (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) and 
"*It's good practice to include other system UI flags (such as SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE) to keep the content from resizing when the system bars hide and show.*" (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting same issue. I also searched on google but not getting solution.
I have apply 100 milliseconds delay on onBackPressed() because I have used setSystemUiVisibility but It is taking time.

**Issue** - Fragment is calling before setSystemUiVisibility because setSystemUiVisibility is taking time so we need to set delay on back press.

```
    public static void hideToolbarFoProfile(Context mContext) {
        Activity mActivity = (Activity) mContext;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window w = Objects.requireNonNull(mActivity).getWindow();
            w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        }

        ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(mActivity)).toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public static void showToolbarFoProfile(Context mContext) {
        Activity mActivity = (Activity) mContext;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window w = Objects.requireNonNull(mActivity).getWindow();
            w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            }
        }

        ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(mActivity)).toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).onBackPressed();
            }, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

**My problem**:

1. I exit from a fullscreen activity to a Dark Action theme activity.
2. I pressed back button on the soft keyboard to go back to fullscreen activity.

The views in the bottom were getting cut off suddenly.

I **solved** this by overriding `onBackPressed()` method and **restarting** my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivityHere.class));
}
```

This should recreate the activity. It is a good hack if you can apply.